# Changing Super Attributes for magento 2 configurable product

Tags: magento2.3

Trying to change the Super attribute for my Magento 2 **configurable** product. Current I have 100 configurable product that has a super attribute `test_colour`, and I've created another attribute called `colour`, and I want to update the configurable product with `colour` instead of `test_colour` programmatically.

Does anyone know how to solve it ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

The methods on this class will create an custom option when this execute . you can use this way create super attribute to your product .

the method deletecustomoption() will remove existing super attribute from the product.

```
<?php
namespace Today\Slot\Block;

class CustomOption extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option $optionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->optionFactory = $optionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
    }

    /**
    * @param string $sku
    */
    public function addCustomOption($productId)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
        $string =  $product->getDemo();
        $str_arr = explode (",", $string);
        $values =array();
        for ($i = 0;$i<count($str_arr);$i++)
        {
            $values[] = [
                'record_id'=>$i,                                        
                'title'=>$str_arr[$i],
                'price'=>10,
                'price_type'=>"fixed",
                'sort_order'=>1,
                'is_delete'=>0
            ];
        }
        $date_from = $product->getchooseDateFrom();
        $date_from = strtotime($date_from);
        $date_to = $product->getchooseDateTo();
        $date_to = strtotime($date_to);
        $dates = array();

            $options = [

                [
                    "sort_order"    => 3,
                    "title"         => "Choose Slots",
                    "price_type"    => "fixed",
                    "price"         => "",
                    "type"          => "multiple",
                    "values"        => $values,
                    "is_require"    => 0
                ]
            ];

        $product->setHasOptions(1);
        $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
        foreach ($options as $arrayOption) {
            $option = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')
                    ->setProductId($productId)
                    ->setStoreId($product->getStoreId())
                    ->addData($arrayOption);
            $option->save();
            $product->addOption($option);
        }
    }

    public function deletecustomoption($productId)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
        if ($product->getOptions()) {
                    foreach ($product->getOptions() as $opt) {
                        $opt->delete();
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

PS : Trying this code directly wont work , unless you change it for yourself